# Flexbox Bootstrap 4 Navbar with additional content vertical aligned and always visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

**The challenge:** create a nav bar that has a brand logo on the left with the navbar-collapse menu and some other call to action/link above it on the right, and have them all vertically positioned.

[image: Layout on large screens]

Seems straight forward, until you want the mobile to look like this:

[image]

How can we achieve this with good responsive css (no negative margins/absolute positioning techniques) and no JS?

I've only come up with the option of printing the Phone number twice on the page, and hiding/showing for various screen sizes:

```
<header>
  <div class="content-above-navbar container">
    <div class="row d-md-none flex-row-reverse">
      <div class="col-auto ml-3"><span class="navbar-text">800-BS4-WEBS</span></div>
      <div class="col-auto p-0"><span class="navbar-text"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container"> 

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="Bootstrap 4 Navbar">Bootstrap 4 Navbar</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all-pages-176" aria-controls="all-pages-176" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>

       <div id="all-pages-176" class="navbar-collapse has-content-above collapse">
        <div class="content-above-nav-menu">
          <div class="float-md-right ml-md-3 d-none d-md-block"><span class="navbar-text">800-BS4-WEBS</span></div>
          <div class="float-md-right d-none d-md-block"><span class="navbar-text"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></span></div>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu-all-pages" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li id="menu-item-1700" class="nav-item active"><a href="/sample-page/" class="nav-link active">Sample Page</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-1701" class="nav-item"><a href="/about/page-markup-and-formatting/" class="nav-link">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-1702" class="nav-item"><a href="/about/page-image-alignment/" class="nav-link">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-1705" class="nav-item"><a href="/level-1/" class="nav-link">Level 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

There's a tiny bit of custom css to make the non-menu info stack up a row and move to the right. See the fiddle link:

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nicscott01/07xhn4vy/1/)

Other markups work for one screen size, but not the other.

Is anybody seeing a solution to this that can be achieved w/ a relatively flat markup?

Comment: Would a pure CSS (and JS just for the mobile menu) solution with clean markup be an option, or does it have to use bootstrap?

Comment: I would be open to any solution...my gut starting point is to use what's already built, but if that's not possible, then use what is available.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Raphael's comment to your question, I'm not entirely sure if the issue could be solved using Bootstrap's styles (other than with duplication of content, as you've shown).

Ignoring Bootstrap, if you only need to support IE11+ then [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) can be used to achieve the layout you've described. I don't have enough experience with Bootstrap to know how well this solution would play with Bootstrap's styles, but here's a barebones example of your layout implemented with pure CSS grids (supporting IE would require adding additional styles that I left out for brevity):

```css
.header {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "c c"
    "l t"
}
.header__logo {
  grid-area: l;
}
.header__contact {
  grid-area: c;
  justify-self: end;
}
.header__menu {
  display: none;
}
.header__toggle {
  grid-area: t;
  margin-left: 1em;
  align-self: center;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "l c"
      "l m"
  }
  .header__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .header__contact {
    align-self: center;
  }
  .header__menu {
    display: flex;
    grid-area: m;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: end;
  }
}

/* debug styles */
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.header > * {
  outline: 1px dashed #cf0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#" class="header__logo"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x80&text=Brand+Logo"/></a>
  <div class="header__contact">
    Contact Us <a href="#">800-BS4-WEBS</a>
  </div>
  <button class="header__toggle">=</button>
  <div class="header__menu">
    <a href="#">Sample Page</a>
    <a href="#">Another Page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! CSS Grid looks very promising and actually the best way to do what I'm wanting to do. I actually didn't realize that CSS grid existed until now!  What I may do is use CSS grid and have fallbacks to the float method above. [This post](https://medium.com/@tallys/bootstrap-to-css-grid-87b3f5f830e4) inspired that thinking.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the Bootstrap 4 grid and **utility** classes...

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/CBsBPCE4oV

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row w-100 no-gutters d-lg-block d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-3 col-6 py-lg-3 order-lg-1 order-2 float-left d-block h-100" href="Bootstrap 4 Navbar">
                Logo
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-text col-lg-6 col-12 order-lg-2 order-1 text-right float-right align-self-end">800-BS4-WEBS</div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed float-right order-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all-pages-176" aria-controls="all-pages-176" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="all-pages-176" class="navbar-collapse collapse float-right col-lg-8 order-4">
                <ul id="menu-all-pages" class="navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-lg-end w-100">
                    <li id="menu-item-1700" class="nav-item active"><a href="/sample-page/" class="nav-link active">Sample Page</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1701" class="nav-item"><a href="/about/page-markup-and-formatting/" class="nav-link">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1702" class="nav-item"><a href="/about/page-image-alignment/" class="nav-link">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-1705" class="nav-item"><a href="/level-1/" class="nav-link">Level 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The only thing I don't like about it is that the logo and the items on the right aren't truly vertically centered. There has to be some sort of calculation of padding/margin to make them appear vertically centered.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to tweak it some more, but it's as close as you'll get with Bootstrap